# Can I get or delete a pod/resource by UID?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

### The problem

It seems that deleting a pod by UID used to be possible, but has been removed (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40121).

It also seems one cannot ***get*** a pod by its resource either (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20572).

(Why did they remove deleting by UID, what is the use of the UID then?)

### Why do I want to use UID in the first place, and not, say, name?

Because I need something like *replicas* and none of the controllers (like Job, Deployment etc) suit my case.
The good thing about UIDs is that kubernetes generates them -- I don't have to worry about differentiating the pods then, I just save the returned UID. So it would be great if I could use it later to delete that particular pod ("replica").

### The question

Is it really not possible to use the UID to ***get***/***delete***?

Is my only option then to take care of differentiating the pods myself (e.g. keep a counter or generate a unique id myself and set it as the name or label)?

Answer (score 5):

This works as a **get** by UID:

> ### Use kubectl `custom-columns`
>
> List all PodName along with its UID of a namespace:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get pods -n <namespace> -o custom-columns=PodName:.metadata.name,PodUID:.metadata.uid
> ```

source: [How do I get the pod ID in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799684/how-do-i-get-the-pod-id-in-kubernetes)

Using `awk` and `xargs` and you can delete with `custom-columns` too.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing to what Laz Rawski already said.

Command to get pod name for a given pod uid:

```
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=PodName:.metadata.name,PodUID:.metadata.uid | grep <pod_uid> | awk '{print $1}'
```

Command to delete a pod for a given pod uid:

```
kubectl delete po $(kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=PodName:.metadata.name,PodUID:.metadata.uid | grep <pod_uid> | awk '{print $1}')
```

Disclaimer: Be careful with delete commands in prod env :)

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are writing a controller to manage a set of replicas using a TPR or [CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/api-extension/custom-resources/)

The short answer is that you should not track pods by UID or name but by using a [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) much like Deployments/ReplicaSets/Services do. If pods match that selector, you can check the Pod's metadata or Pod spec to see if it needs to be 
deleted for some reason.