# Trying to get a particular podIP of a pod from kubectl get po

Tags: kubectl

able to list all pods and IP with this command

```
kubectl get po -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.podIP}{"\n"}{end}'
```

but trying to get a podIP of a pod with a podname. How to retrieve the podIP which met the condition of pod name.
Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the pod ID in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799684/how-do-i-get-the-pod-id-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a specific pod name and namespace to your kubectl command.

> `kubectl get po $POD_NAME -n $NAMESPACE -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.podIP}{"\n"}{end}'`